# camel : Cannot acquire read lock - Hebrew name

Tags: apache-camel

when trying to read a file using camel file (consumer) with Hebrew (Windows-1255) name , with readLock=changed I'm getting error :
org.apache.camel.component.file.strategy.FileChangedExclusiveReadLockStrategy - Cannot acquire read lock within 2000 millis. Will skip the file
How can I solve this ?
here is the error :

```
> 2017-10-10 11:03:00.882 [Camel (incomingFileHandlerCamelContext)
> thread #1 -
> file:///inbal/Vaults/Swiftnesstest/Distribution/Pension_Gemel/Interfaces/In]
> ERROR org.apache.camel.processor.DefaultErrorHandler - Failed delivery
> for (MessageId: a409d31f-9c38-40a0-8874-578e29de46c5 on ExchangeId:
> dfe13fc7-750f-4295-9a3a-57d31e9f198f). Exhausted after delivery
> attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException: No body
> available of type: java.lang.String but has value:
> GenericFile[/inbal/Vaults/Swiftnesstest/Distribution/Pension_Gemel/Interfaces/In/���.txt]
> of type: org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFile on: ���.txt.
> Caused by: Error during type conversion from type: java.lang.String to
> the required type: byte[] with value [Body is file based:
> GenericFile[/inbal/Vaults/Swiftnesstest/Distribution/Pension_Gemel/Interfaces/In/���.txt]]
> due java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> /inbal/Vaults/Swiftnesstest/Distribution/Pension_Gemel/Interfaces/In/���.txt
> (No such file or directory).
> Exchange[dfe13fc7-750f-4295-9a3a-57d31e9f198f]. Caused by:
> [org.apache.camel.TypeConversionException - Error during type
> conversion from type: java.lang.String to the required type: byte[]
> with value [Body is file based:
> GenericFile[/inbal/Vaults/Swiftnesstest/Distribution/Pension_Gemel/Interfaces/In/���.txt]]
> due java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> /inbal/Vaults/Swiftnesstest/Distribution/Pension_Gemel/Interfaces/In/���.txt
> (No such file or directory)]
```

Comment: You can turn on readLock logging level to see what happens - `readLockLoggingLevel=DEBUG`. It does smell of some kind of JVM encoding problem. There is some JVM ENV/system property you can configure for files.

Comment: yes the problem is only in linux . no problem in windows

Comment: I added the error